# Asp.NET 5 + Class Library (package) - how to include static content like CSS and JS file

Tags: asp.net, nuget-package

I have a "Class Library (Package)" which creates a Nuget package with some CSS and JS content. The static files as inside the "content/" folder.

If I reference this Nuget package in a project created using the "ASP.NET 4.6.1 Template", all the files from Nuget "content/" folder are copied in to the empty project root. Which is fine.

If I reference this Nuget in a project created by "ASP.NET 5 Template", no files are copied. Is it some limitation of a new "ASP.NET 5 Templates" ?

I know I can use Bower for static files, but I do not want to end up with two packages, one for client side(Bower, css, js) and one for "Server" side (Nuger, DLL).

Comment: You could embed the assets in the assembly. Scott Hanselman discusses how Thinktecture Identity Server does that to serve a UI on [his blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ThinktectureIdentityManagerAsAReplacementForTheASPNETWebSiteAdministrationTool.aspx). I don't know how well this would work with ASP.NET 5, but it's worth a look.

Comment: Yes, that's good for Razor Views and it is actually what I'm using for that. But for CSS,JS, Images... I think it is better to server them directly(over HTTP).

Comment: This is (I believe) related to this issue: [NuGet/Home#1792](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1792). It's not available yet, which is pretty frustrating.